# Is it possible to have CMake + SWIG + Python auto include from C++ header(s)?

Tags: python, c++, cmake, swig

I've just gotten into learning C++ modules for Python using SWIG and CMake.

Looking at 'UseSWIG' documentation, it seem it's possible to have CMake auto-include e.g  from my simple "hello world" test. But, i've been unable so far to be successful at it **without having to add `%include std_string.i` to my *'hello.i'* file.**

With the following *(which i simply snipped from [obs-python](https://github.com/TheAndyRoid/obs-python/blob/master/swig/CMakeLists.txt)'s github)* added to my CMakeLists.txt :

```
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(hello.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-modern")
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(hello.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-builtin")
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(hello.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-modernargs")
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(hello.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall")
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(hello.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-importall")
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(hello.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-py3")
```

The library will then appear to compile fine, without having to add `%include std_string.i` . However, trying to use the built module in python will then result in:

```
<Swig Object of type 'std::string *' at 0x7fb743896270>
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'std::string *', no destructor found.
```

I'm wondering if anyone would be willing to provide a short example of what might be missing.

Or is it actually necessary to have 'std_string.i' included in my 'hello.i' regardless of `<string>` being included in my c++ header?

*(Without either one of those two, make will, as expected, state that `<string>` can't be found.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std_string.i` contains the typemaps required for SWIG to understand `std::string`.  You have to include it in the `.i` file if you wrap functions that use `std::string`, or SWIG will just generate opaque wrappers for objects it doesn't understand (e.g. `Swig Object of type 'std::string *'`).

Note you generally **do not** want to use `-includeall` or `-importall`.  You generally do not want to generate SWIG wrappers for every class and function included, recursively.

Comment: 'Note you generally **do not** want to use -includeall or -importall'. I'll keep that in mind. Thanks.